# Testbench errors when using Xilinx Logicore Boxes

Tags: filtering, vhdl, libraries, fpga, xilinx

I'm making a filter bank with user inputs, right now I'm trying to test this current design out, and see if anything needs to be fixed up. Currently, I can generate  a bit stream and see my LED's change. However in the test-bench, the LED wave form does not move from it's initial zero state. Also, my filter does not seem to be working at all.

I used the LogiCore to make a FIR, and a DDS compiler to make a sine wave to stimulate it. And I am using a DSP48 to get amplitude modulation of the output signal.

I have the two ISim libraries I believe that I need. I' am not quite sure why my outputs are not being assigned?

I have looked at the documentation, and I am using Xilinx's ISIM, so I don't need to recompile the simulation libraries, I belive... am I wrong in thinking this?

There is a spot in the middle of my simulation where my data is present, I don't know if it's valid though.

Any help is apriciated.

My Top Module.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    11:56:05 03/25/2015 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    Filter_Box - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;             

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity Filter_Box is
    Port (  Board_Clock     : in    STD_LOGIC;
                --Filter_Clock  : in    STD_LOGIC;
                --Input_Sample  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
                --Out_data      : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
                led                 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
                Mixer_Controls : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0));
end Filter_Box;

architecture Behavioral of Filter_Box is

--
--  Component statements here, these should all be filters and/or DSP cores
--      unless otherwise noted.

--uses 1 dsp core and 1 bram
component Low_Pass
    port (
    clk : in std_logic;                             --core clock
    rfd : out std_logic;                                --filter ready for data flag
    rdy : out std_logic;                                --filter output ready flag
    din : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);     --data in (To be filterd)
    dout    : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));   --data out (has been filtered)
end component;


-- Uses 1 dsp core (3 dsp registers)
COMPONENT Mixer_controls_DSP_slice
  PORT (
    clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
    a : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
    b : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
    p : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END COMPONENT;


-- This sine wave box is for testing purposes only
COMPONENT Sine_Wave
  PORT (
    clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
    pinc_in : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
    sine : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END COMPONENT;


--
--  Singal instantiations
--
signal rfd  : std_logic;
signal rdy  : std_logic;
signal din  :   std_logic_vector (15 downto 0) := X"0000";
signal dout :   std_logic_vector (15 downto 0) := X"0000";
signal Low_Pass_Final_Data_Signal : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0) := X"0000";
signal pinc_in  : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0) := X"0001";


begin


--
--This register will controll all the singals
--      in the module and should direct the acctual
--      signals to their formal signals
Internal_Signal_Traffic_Controller : 
    process (Board_Clock) is 
        variable count : std_logic_vector (31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    begin
    if rising_edge(Board_Clock) then
        led <= count(31) & count (30) & count(29) & count(28);
        count := count +1;
    end if;
end process;



--low pass filter instance, must use the filter clock,
--  currently filter clock is set to 500 MHZ
--      This will be the DSP clock as well
Low_Pass_Filter_Instance_Number_One : 
    Low_Pass port map (
            clk => Board_Clock,
            rfd => rfd,
            rdy => rdy,
            din => din,
            dout => dout);

-- Mixer instance to multiply filter outputs 
--      by fifo controll inputs, the output 
--      should then be passed to the adder core 
--  to reassemble the signal and put it out
--      to whichever port is needed
Filter_Instance_One_Amplitude_Controller : 
Mixer_controls_DSP_slice PORT MAP (
    clk => Board_Clock,
    a => Mixer_Controls,
    b => dout,
    p => Low_Pass_Final_Data_Signal
  );

-- This is the sinewave testing box
--      it should be deleted or commented
--          out after testing has been done
Sine_Wave_Testing_Box : Sine_Wave
  PORT MAP (
    clk => Board_Clock,
    pinc_in => pinc_in,
    sine => din
  );

--Out_data <= Low_Pass_Final_Data_Signal;


end Behavioral;
```

My Test bench

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer:
--
-- Create Date:   14:00:04 03/25/2015
-- Design Name:   
-- Module Name:   D:/Dropbox/ECE.CLASSES/SeniorD/Filter_Top_Module/Filter_Box/Test_Bench_of_Filter_Module.vhd
-- Project Name:  Filter_Box
-- Target Device:  
-- Tool versions:  
-- Description:   
-- 
-- VHDL Test Bench Created by ISE for module: Filter_Box
-- 
-- Dependencies:
-- 
-- Revision:
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments:
--
-- Notes: 
-- This testbench has been automatically generated using types std_logic and
-- std_logic_vector for the ports of the unit under test.  Xilinx recommends
-- that these types always be used for the top-level I/O of a design in order
-- to guarantee that the testbench will bind correctly to the post-implementation 
-- simulation model.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

library UNIMACRO;  
use UNIMACRO.Vcomponents.all;


ENTITY Test_Bench_of_Filter_Module IS
END Test_Bench_of_Filter_Module;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF Test_Bench_of_Filter_Module IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT Filter_Box
    PORT(
         Board_Clock : IN  std_logic;
         --Out_data : OUT  std_logic;
         led : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         Mixer_Controls : IN  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal Board_Clock : std_logic := '0';
   signal Mixer_Controls : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := (others => '1');

    --Outputs
   signal Out_data : std_logic;
   signal led : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant Board_Clock_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: Filter_Box PORT MAP (
          Board_Clock => Board_Clock,
          --Out_data => Out_data,
          led => led,
          Mixer_Controls => Mixer_Controls
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   Board_Clock_process :process
   begin
        Board_Clock <= '0';
        wait for Board_Clock_period/2;
        Board_Clock <= '1';
        wait for Board_Clock_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      wait for 100 ns;  

      wait for Board_Clock_period*10;

      -- insert stimulus here 

      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

Here is a waveform Example of what I get, and where my curious data is alive, but then goes back to being X's.

[image: The rest of the simulation, the Dout and low pass final data are X's]

Edit: These DSP cores are designed to be driven at 500MHz and the filter has a sample frequency of 100KHz and a low-pass cutoff of 400Hz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FIR core from Xilinx doesn't accept and generate 1 sample per clock, but rather 1 every *N* clock cycles, where *N* depends on the parameters of the filter, particularly its length and architecture.

I recommend you to look at the FIR compiler datasheet, and start monitoring the signals *rfd* (ready for data, indicate when the input is read) and *rdy* (ready, indicate when the output is valid).

Comment: This answer, along with  increasing the test benches clock period proved to solve the issue I was having. Thank you.